# How to send and access Javascript object to/in code behind file in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, json

I am trying to pass the Object data to the code behind file `aspx.cs` file
and how to access  it  from `.cs` file.

I added `json.js` and `newtonsoftjson.dll` into my project

```
var Obj = [{ 'username': 'Kesav', 'subj': '2', 'desc': '3' },
            { 'username': 'Kesav1', 'subj': '3', 'desc': '34'}];

            $.ajax
                ({

                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: "JsonTry.aspx/InsertData",
                    data:"{'username': 'Kesav', 'subj': '2', 'desc': '3'}"
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        var obj = data.d;
                        if (obj == 'true') {
                            Submitted Successfully");
                        }
                    },
                    error: function (result) {
                        alert("Error");
                    }
                });
```

Code Behind File

```
[WebMethod]
public static string InsertData(string username, string subj, string desc)
{

}
```

Comment: What error are you having? In the `ajax` properties you don't have a comma after the property `data`.

Comment: Sorry I tried with comma  this code is working. I need to create an object which contains multiple key value pairs and convert them into json object and send them to .cs page.

Comment: After sending to .cs page I need to retrieve them